# How can i convert google chrome history to a .txt file using python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I need a python script to extract a list of visted urls to a txt file for a project i'm working on.

I have tried sevral codes I found online and none of them seem to work for me.

(java is also fine although python is preferred.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**sqlite3**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module to read the Chrome history file.

```
import sqlite3

history_db = 'C:\\Users\\USERID\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
c = sqlite3.connect(history_db)
cursor = c.cursor()
select_statement = "SELECT urls.url, urls.visit_count FROM urls, visits WHERE urls.id = visits.url;"
cursor.execute(select_statement)
results = cursor.fetchall()


with open('PATH_TO_TXT\\history.txt', 'a') as file:
    for i in results:
        file.write("{0} - {1}\n".format(i[0], i[1]))
```

[More info](https://geekswipe.net/technology/computing/analyze-chromes-browsing-history-with-python/)

Comment: thank you Rakesh, but i have tried something vary simiular  and i get an exeption:     "sqlite3.operationalError: database is locked"

Answer (score 0):

just close chrome and the database will be unlocked simple

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you elaborate?